# Condition for memory access conflict in memory-banked vector processors

Tags: vectorization, hardware, cpu-architecture, processor

The Hennessy-Patterson book on Computer Architecture (Quantitative Approach 5ed) says that in a vector architecture with multiple memory banks, a bank conflict can happen if the following condition is met (Page 279 in 5ed):

(Number of banks) / LeastCommonMultiple(Number of banks, Stride) < Bank busy time

However, I think it should be GreatestCommonFactor instead of LCM, because memory conflict would occur if the **effective number of banks** you have is less than the busy time. By effective number of banks I mean this - let's say you have 8 banks, and a stride of 2. Then effectively you have 4 banks, because the memory accesses will be lined up only at four banks (e.g, let's say your accesses are all even numbers, starting from 0, then your accesses will be lined up at banks 0,2,4,6).

In fact, this formula even fails for the example given right below it. *Suppose we have 8 memory banks with busy time of 6 clock cycles, with total memory latency of 12 clock cycles, how long will it take to complete a 64-element vector load with stride of 1?* - Here they calculate the time as 12+64=76 clock cycles. However, memory bank conflict will occur according to the condition given, so we clearly can't have one access per cycle (64 in the equation).

Am I getting it wrong, or has the wrong formula managed to survive 5 editions of this book (unlikely)?

Comment: That sounds right if it works like Intel Sandybridge's L1 cache, where each pair of cache lines (128B total) is divided into eight 16B banks, and concurrent loads from the same bank in different lines is a bank conflict.  (But two reads of the same bank in the same line can happen in the same cycle).  [Agner Fog's microarch pdf](http://agner.org/optimize/) describes it.  Haswell and later don't have bank conflicts, so this only applies to SnB and IvB, the first two generations of Intel microarchitectures that support two reads per clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCD(banks, stride) should come into it; your argument about that is correct.

Let's try this for a few different strides and see what we get, 
for number of banks = `b = 8`.

```
# generated with the calc(1) function
define f(s) { print s, "     |   ", lcm(s,8), "    |   ", gcd(s,8), "    |   ", 8/lcm(s,8), "      |   ", 8/gcd(s,8) }`

stride | LCM(s,b) | GCF(s,b) | b/LCM(s,b) |  b/GCF(s,b)
1      |    8     |    1     |    1       |    8     # 8 < 6 = false: no conflict
2      |    8     |    2     |    1       |    4     # 4 < 6 = true:  conflict
3      |    24    |    1     |   ~0.333   |    8     # 8 < 6 = false: no conflict
4      |    8     |    4     |    1       |    2     # 2 < 6 = true: conflict
5      |    40    |    1     |    0.2     |    8
6      |    24    |    2     |   ~0.333   |    4
7      |    56    |    1     |   ~0.143   |    8
8      |    8     |    8     |    1       |    1
9      |    72    |    1     |   ~0.111   |    8

x         >=8        2^0..3      <=1          1 2 4 or 8
```

**b/LCM(s,b) is always <=1, so it always predicts conflicts.**

I think GCF (aka GCD) looks right for the stride values I've looked at so far.  You only have a problem if the stride doesn't distribute the accesses over all the banks, and that's what b/GCF(s,b) tells you.

---

Stride = 8 should be the worst-case, using the same bank every time.  gcd(8,8) = lcm(8,8) = 8.  So both expressions give 8/8 = 1 which is less than the bank busy/recovery time, thus correctly predicting conflicts.

Stride=1 is of course the best case (no conflicts if there are enough banks to hide the busy time).  gcd(8,1) = 1 correctly predicts no conflicts: (8/1 = 8, which is not less than 6).  lcm(8,1) = 8.  (`8/8 < 6` is true) incorrectly predicts conflicts.

Comment: *So both expressions seem to be bogus, giving 8/8 = 1 which is less than the bank busy/recovery time, thus predicting no conflicts* - I think there is a small error here. The condition states that if the inequality is *satisfied*, then there *is* a conflict. For stride 8, the inequality is satisfied, and hence there *is* a conflict. For stride 1, gcd predicts *no* conflicts instead. And in fact for stride 1, there indeed won't be any conflicts - because you have 8 banks and busy time is 6. So by the time you warp back to bank#1, you've spent 8 cycles, and hence the first bank is free again.

Comment: @ParthThakkar: Yeah, not just a small error; my whole conclusion was wrong!  I got mixed up and inverted conflict / no-conflict at some point.  After fixing that, I think you're right that GCD works in H&P's formula.  Congrats on discovering a mistake, you should send them an email to let them know.

Comment: I guess I'll be doing that. Thanks for confirming. :)